# How to save parsed dates pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm reading a CSV file and parsing dates.

```
train = pd.read_csv('sales_train.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

date    
2015-10-10
2015-09-10
2015-10-14
2015-10-22
2015-03-10
```

At this point the dataframe is correctly parsed. If I need to access to same dataframe another day I don't want to parse date column again and spend 10 minutes to compute. How can I save this dataframe which has parsed dates?

Comment: I may not understand you, but databases?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some of your code and example data?

If you're running something like `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` but not saving it anywhere, try:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After to parse dates it's recommended to save dataframe in **Parquet** or **HDF** format as follows:

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
df.to_hdf('df.h5','table_name',append=True)
```

If I want to read it,

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
df.to_hdf('df.h5','table_name',append=True)
```

**Note 1:** Important to install this libraries

```
conda install fastparquet pyarrow python-snappy -c conda-forge
```

**Note 2:** Parquet format is smaller than hdf